# Getting incorrect ouput when passing a string variable, defined by user input, to a setter method in Java

Tags: java, input

New to Java. I understand that strings are immutable, but I don't understand why the output here is the way it is.

The goal: I'm trying to ask a user a question "What class do you want to be?", the user answers. Their answer is stored in a string variable (classEntered), and passed into the setClass method which returns starting HP and starting gold based on what was input into classEntered.

The problem: When The user enters what kind of character they want to be (i.e. warlock or warrior), playerClass  gets updated properly. But the output (startingHP / startingGold) do not respond correctly.

Here is the code:

```
    class Player {

        String playerName;
        String playerClass;
        int startingGold;
        int startingHP;

        public void setName(String playerName){
            this.playerName = playerName;
        }

        public void setClass(String newClass){
            playerClass = newClass;
            if(playerClass == "Warlock"){
                startingHP = 100;
                startingGold = 25;
            }else if (playerClass == "Warrior"){
                startingHP = 150;
                startingGold = 30; 
            }
        }
    }

    public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // practice code: if playerClass defined this way the output is correct
            Player player1 = new Player();
            player1.setName("Jordan");
            player1.setClass("Warlock");

            System.out.println("Your name is: " + player1.playerName);
            System.out.println("You're a " + player1.playerClass);
            System.out.println("Your starting HP is " + player1.startingHP + " your starting gold is " + player1.startingGold);

            Player player2 = new Player();
            player2.setName("Jorel");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("What class do you choose? ");
            String classEntered = sc.nextLine();
            player2.setClass(classEntered);
            System.out.println("testing " + player2.playerClass);
            //output is incorrect when playerClass defined via scanner
            System.out.println("Your name is: " + player2.playerName);
            System.out.println("You're a " + player2.playerClass);
            System.out.println("Your starting HP is " + player2.startingHP + " your starting gold is " + player2.startingGold);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Compare string values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with `==`.

Comment: also, what happens if they enters something that's neither Warlock or Warrior?

Answer (score 1):

`String`s in Java are case-sensitive. When your player inputs his class, he must write it **exactly** as you're comparing it in the `setClass` API.

Secondly, you must use `equals` method to comparing string contents.

```
if(playerClass.equals("Warlock"))
{
    startingHP = 100;
    startingGold = 25;
}
else if (playerClass.equals("Warrior"))
{
    startingHP = 150;
    startingGold = 30; 
}
```

In your code, the code wasn't entering neither branch of the IF statement.

**More:**

- Use constants for your classes, or even separate classes/enums.
- Make setters and getters for your HP and Gold. Respect encapsulation.
- Make sure you tell the use that a class doesn't exist, if he enters "elf", for example.
- To make your classes case-insensitive, use `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings, instead of `equals`